# Double query with WHERE IN, or join

Tags: php, mysql, select, innodb

We have two major mysql (innodb) tabels. Both containing millions of records.

Here is a example of our structure

```
-- table 1 --
primary_id
child_id
```

-

```
-- table 2 --
id
structure
contents
```

It's not like this, but for the question it's the same.

We need to fetch about 50.000 records from table 2, that are linked to primary id 2022.

What is the most quickly way to do this.
This is what we came up with:

1) 
Do a select with a join on the two tables.

2)
Do a select of the ids in table 1 *getting 200.000 records* and then a select WHERE IN (all id's) and a filter on the structure there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use WHERE IN, itreally slows your querry.. join would def be the better option

Answer (score 0):

i would go with a join. Select records from first table with the primary_id you need and join the second table on the ids